# Calculate total amount from Upwork after fee deduction using Python

Tags: python, if-statement, percentage, boolean-logic, upwork-api

I am trying to calculate total money after deduction of a Fee from Upwork. I found [this](https://weareindy.com/upwork-fee-calculator) website that does this but I want to make it using Python. Here is the guidelines from Upwork:

> $0-$500 in earnings from a client: 20% service fee applied to earnings.

> $500.01-$10,000 in earnings from a client: 10% service fee.

> $10,000.01 or more in earnings from a client: 5% service fee.

The code:

```
budget = int(input("Enter the price (USD): $"))

if 0 <= budget <= 500:
    cut = int((20/100)*budget)
    budget = budget - cut
elif 501.01 <= budget <= 10000:
    cut = int((10/100)*budget)
    budget = budget - cut
elif budget >= 10000.01:
    cut = int((5/100)*budget)
    budget = budget - cut

print(f'Total price after Upwork Fee is ${budget}.')
```

According to Upwork,

> On a $600 project with a new client, your freelancer service fee would be 20% on the first $500 and 10% on the remaining $100. Your earnings after fees would be $490.

I made this calculator but it works only for the first condition `$0-$500 in earnings`. If the budget is `$600`, I will get `$490` but here I am getting `$540`. Can someone help me out what went wrong?

--Update--

I also tried this but of no use:

```
budget = int(input("Enter the price (USD): $"))

a = 0 <= budget <= 500
b = 501.01 <= budget <= 10000
c = budget >= 10000.01

cut1 = int((20/100)*budget)
cut2 = int((10/100)*budget)
cut3 = int((5/100)*budget)    
           

if a:
    cut = cut1
    budget = budget - cut
if a and b:
    cut = cut2
    budget = budget - cut
if a and b and c:
    cut = cut3
    budget = budget - cut

print(f'Total price after Upwork Fee is ${budget}.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
budget = int(input("Enter the price (USD): $"))

def discount(money,percent):
    cut = int((percent/100)*money)
    money= money- cut
    return money

if 0 <= budget <= 500:
    budget = discount(budget ,20)
elif 500.01 <= budget <= 10000:
    budget2 = discount(500 ,20)
    budget = discount(budget-500 ,10)
    budget = budget + budget2
elif budget >= 10000.01:
    budget3 = discount(500 ,20)
    budget2 = discount(10000 ,10)
    budget = discount(budget-10500 ,5)
    budget = budget + budget2 + budget3

    

print(f'Total price after Upwork Fee is ${budget}.')
```

Comment: If the budget is `$35000`, according to [this](https://weareindy.com/upwork-fee-calculator) website I mentioned in my question, it should be `$32700`, but with your method, I am getting `$31450`.

Comment: Only the last `elif` condition seems to problematic here. Because if the total budget is `$10500`, it should give `$9425` but your method gives `$9400`. Can you please update it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, two things are wrong here:

1. you substract the cut from the budget.
2. you apply the cut to the max value, not the "diapason" value.

My guess is that you need something like this pesudo-code:

```
if budget > 0
cut+= 0.20*MIN(Budget, 500)
if budget > 500
cut+= 0.10*MIN(Budget-500, 9500) // We already applied the cut to the first 500
if budget > 10000
cut+= 0.05*(Budget-10000) // we already applied a cut to the first 10000
```

So:

1. do not modify budget
2. accumulate cut
3. substract it at the end.